# Python Selenium selecting option using Select (element not visible?)

Tags: python, selenium

I've tried to use a few approaches mentioned in similar questions with no luck. In the HTML source code there is clearly 'value' and 'text' properties, but I cannot seem to access those when I use selenium.webdriver to access these?

Note selection lead to change in data on the page...

---

**Edit2:**

Guy has pointed out below that the actual drop down maybe a  element instead of the  element. However using el.click() simply flickers and does not open the drop-down.

---

**EDIT1:**
The  and  elements can now be identified but I am unable to make an selection. I believe the page is also in javascript and hence I'm unsure if this affects methods used.

---

**Original post:**

Webpage:
https://www.racv.com.au/on-the-road/driving-maintenance/fuel-prices.html

HTML code of selection, for visibility, some options omitted:

```html
<select name="filter-select-6" id="filter-select-6" class="js-dropdown js-select-map js-filter-select" data-filter="#filter-list-60 .js-tab-item" data-url="/bin/racv/fuelprice" style="display: none;" data-parsley-id="3">                            
    <option value="11" data-index="0">LRP</option>
    <option value="2" selected="true" data-index="0">Unleaded</option>
    <option value="3" data-index="0">Diesel</option>
    <option value="8" data-index="0">Premium Unleaded 98</option>
</select>
```

I believe I can select the Select element without problem:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

url = 'https://www.racv.com.au/on-the-road/driving-maintenance/fuel-prices.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

fuel_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('filter-select-6'))
```

When I print the options, I get:

```py
for fuel_option in fuel_select.options:
    print(fuel_option)

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a10aa750fa59f4412e0bea4d7aae990", element="0.5927271524692566-2")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a10aa750fa59f4412e0bea4d7aae990", element="0.5927271524692566-3")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a10aa750fa59f4412e0bea4d7aae990", element="0.5927271524692566-8")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a10aa750fa59f4412e0bea4d7aae990", element="0.5927271524692566-11")>
```

Using select():

```py
for fuel_option in fuel_select.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if fuel_option.text == "Diesel":
        fuel_option.select()
```

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/file.py", line 18, in <module>
    fuel_option.Select()
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Using click() or using any of the select_by_xxx():

```py
for fuel_option in fuel_select.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if fuel_option.text == "Diesel":
        fuel_option.click()

#or using select_by_xxx
fuel_select.select_by_value('8')
```

Error:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Can you navigate us to that drop down ? That drop down is inside a div element. That Div has property called hidden.

Comment: Sure, I just inspected the dropdown which defaults to 'UNLEADED'. I believe it should be the <div> right below class="hidden", it is inside <div class="fuel-price">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select is a wrapper around the WebElement, select() is not a valid method. Please refer to [Select doc](https://github.com/browserstack/selenium-webdriver-python/blob/master/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py)

Have you tried using select_by_value:

```
fuel_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('filter-select-6'))
fuel_select.select_by_value("8")
```

Or by visible text:

```
fuel_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('filter-select-6'))
fuel_select.select_by_visible_text("Premium Unleaded 98")
```

**EDIT1**
Try to click() first to make the dropdown visible:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('filter-select-6')
el.click()
fuel_select = Select(el)
```

**EDIT2:**
I believe your issue is more related to the fact that you use the css property `style="display: none;"`
You should not be able to see the dropdown manually either.

Please refer to the [css syntax doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) for more detail

When using None: *The element is completely removed*

Might not be "ideal" but you can change the value of this property to make it visible again using:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "block";', el)
```

Code would then look like:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('filter-select-6')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "block";', el)

fuel_select = Select(el)
fuel_select.select_by_value("8")
```

**EDIT3:**
Just noticed you provided the website! Very useful.
So the dropdown is hidden being another element and only made available once clicked.

Here's the code and it worked for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# Get the first element and tap on it, note you might have to tap few time.
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.chosen-single > div')
action = TouchActions(driver)
action.tap(el).perform()

# once the dropdown is open it does not seems that the Select el is the one to use
els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.active-result')
for el in els:
    if el.text == 'Diesel':
        el.click()
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Nic. Just tried your recommendation and returned with same error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 16, in <module>
    fuel_select.select_by_value("8")' selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Would you get same result if you click first then use select? Try ```el = driver.find_element_by_id('filter-select-6'), el.click().``` Then assign that ```el``` to Select ```fuel_select = Select(el)```

Comment: I think `click()` is only a method for `webdriver` but not for `Select(webriver.find_element_by_id()`? `fuel_select.click()` is returning `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: Correct you need to click on the element, I have edited the code for more visibility

Comment: This is still coming up as `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated`. Could this be to do with another <div> which displays the selection of <select> under the same <label> ?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Your issue is related to the fact the ```display``` is set to None. Which remove the element from being visible at all

Comment: Using a normal Chrome browser and mouse input, the drop-down does appear. And selection also affects other Objects on the page also...

Comment: Got it, just noticed you posted the website. Check the third edit. I tested the code and worked for me

Comment: My hero! Worked like a charm, however I had not even seen css selector nor TouchAction before. Thank you!